# jQuery ajax call not firing issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is the code block I am using. In IE this event fires and works good. But in other browser, it is not working.

Any idea how to fix this or get more details about the error ( if there is any!)

```
$.ajax('/stockquote.asmx/GetQuote',
{
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
        successmessage = 'Data was succesfully captured';
        $("label#successmessage").text(successmessage);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        successmessage = 'Error';
        $("label#successmessage").text(successmessage);
    },
    complete: function () {

    }
});
```

Comment: Get rid of `contentType: 'application/json'`.  You are not sending any data, so you don't need to set the *request* header.

Comment: I will try. Thanks for immediate response.

Comment: Also, when developing/debugging, you should be getting the *full* error messages.  Change your `error` function to `error: function(jqXHR, status, error){ console.log(status, error); }`.

Comment: Why are you using `type: 'POST'` when you are not sending any data?

Comment: values are in  session object.

Comment: Then there's no reason to use `POST` here.

Comment: I think by default it uses Post.

Comment: By default, [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) uses `GET`.